# Variable-length button with icon and text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml

How can I create a button, like the one below, that have variable-length text values:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5DOJ.png

The icon is an image (drawable) and the text can be of various length. The button itself has a padding of `15px` all around.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any idea?

Comment: I always imagine this kind of questions, "I'm bored to search, lets ask stack"

Comment: You are a beginner that we can see. But as a toddler you go with baby steps, maybe first use a proper nick name for stack community, accept the answer when you are provided with one, use google, or bing if you like, use small words be polite even when criticized. And a patience is a virtue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this your Button's XML for the icon

```
android:drawableLeft="yourdrawable"
```

and this for the width

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```